# Environment specific variables in sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets

I'm use Rails 3.2 built in sprockets functionality to compile static assets. Is it possible to compile javascript with environment specific variables?

So I would like to do something like this

/assets/javascripts/myfile.js

---

```
 //lots of code
 script.src =
        ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') +
                'some.metrics.site/projects/<%=ENV_SPECIFIC_TOKEN%>.js';
  //lots of other code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprockets lets you append any number of preprocessors to a filename. Add a `.erb` to the end, and it will be first interpreted as ERB and then output as a JavaScript file.

`mv assets/javascripts/myfile.js assets/javascripts/myfile.js.erb`

Check out the Rails Asset Pipeline guide on [JavaScript/CoffeeScript and ERB](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#javascript-coffeescript-and-erb).

Comment: Thanks, it's a good idea but this means the file will be recompiled on every request. I was asking about a one time compilation (per deploy, let's say)

Comment: Revisiting this, my previous comment wasn't (exactly) correct. If deploy time pre-compile is turned on then it will just compile it once, as needed

Comment: You should always [pre-compile your assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) in production, and you should turn off the asset pipeline completely in production by setting `config.assets.compile = false` in production.rb.

Answer (score 0):

Any update for this issue?

Using the .erb extension solves the problem but not when you precompile assets.

In my case, I need to precompile the assets for my staging environment. When I do **rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=staging**, I can see in the js assets generated that my environment variable is not defined and thus the string interpolation results in an empty string.

The problem is (I think) that the environment variable definition is in config/application.rb, which is not called while generating assets.

I think that the gem Capistrano may help by adding some tasks before generating the assets, but if we can define some environment variables while generating the assets (in the CLI for example), it would be better.

Comment: If you update your application.rb to have 

     ```config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true```

That should solve the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do it because I use heroku and it requires this to be false: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Comment: I solved this by adding a rake task where I call first the environment initialisation function and then precompile assets.

Comment: On heroku you need to do two things

1. Add rails_12factor gem
2. Setup user-env-compile variable https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline